# Angular2 - How to scroll dialog to top

Tags: angular

Need to scroll dialog to top so that alert comes into view after form submission. 
Tried this but doesn't seem to work on dialogs.

```
window.scrollTo(0,0);
```

Comment: So you want to scroll to the top if you submit a form, and there should be a dialog there? Or is the dialog some scrollable content that needs scrolling?

Comment: Open dialog -> long form in dialog -> submit -> scroll to top of dialog to show error alert if there is any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById('formsubmit').onclick=function(){
  document.getElementById('form').scrollTop = 0;
  return false;
}
```

```css
input {
  display:block;
}

.form {
  height:100px;
  overflow-y:auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>form</h1>
  <div class="form" id="form">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="text">
    
    <input type="submit" id="formsubmit">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried it out but doesn't seem to work. It looks like the dialog is not affected by scrollTop. The value is still 0 although I have scrolled to the bottom by checking the value before and after doing "document.getElementById('form').scrollTop = 0;"

Comment: @KarlisFilipsons are you sure the dialog is scrollable? It could be a `div` inside the dialog instead.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I wasn't using it on the right element. Works like a charm now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Although this question has been marked as the answer, this isn't the angular-y way of scrolling to the top. A better way of doing this is by doing:

```js
@ViewChild('scrollContainer') private myScrollContainer: ElementRef;
  
constructor(private _renderer: Renderer2) {}
onFormSubmit() {
    this._renderer.setProperty(this.scrollContainer.nativeElement, 'scrollTop', this.scrollContainer.nativeElement.scrollHeight);
}
```

```css
input {
  display:block;
}

.form {
  height:100px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h1>form</h1>
    <div #scrollContainer class="form">
        <input type="text">
        <input type="text">
        <input type="text">
        <input type="text">
        <input type="text">
        <input type="text">
        <input type="text">
        <input type="submit" (click)="onFormSubmit()">
    </div>
</div>
```

A good rule of thumb is that if you see ```document`` then you're not doing something the angular way, but the vanilla js way.

A big mistake that people commonly make is that they use the ElementRef to setValues, properties, css. Per the angular docs, ElementRef should be used as a last resort. You can read more about that here: https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef

Comment: I think that your suggested code implements a scroll to bottom (and not to the top)... To scroll to the top I think this property should be set to 0, like that: `this._renderer.setProperty(this.scrollContainer.nativeElement, 'scrollTop', 0)`

Comment: Realise this is old, just want to point out that in new versions of Angular (I think from 9 or 10) you should be getting a RendererFactory2 in the constructor and using that to get a Renderer2 by using rendererFactory2.createRenderer().

Answer (score 0):

Use the plain js `scrollIntoView` [1]

```
function scrollIntoView() {
  $('#modalId')[0].scrollIntoView();
}
```

Not an angular way but it works.

[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView